# MySQL Workbench failing to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've just installed the latest version of the MySQL Workbench (8.0.13 Build 13780177) onto a windows 10 machine and I'm getting an error connecting to a MySQL Server instance.  I'm getting back Error 1045 when I test the connection.  It doesn't seem to be sending the password in the connection string as the text in the error message says:

> Error: Access denied for user (using password: NO)

I am providing a password and the exact connection works on another machine running Workbench 6.3.9.  The connection does not use SSL.

What would cause the error to say that no password is being used when a password is being supplied?

**Edit**
I downgraded to the 6.3 version and not it's able to connect.

Are there different connection default between 8.0 and 6.3 that could cause the failure?

Comment: may be the user you provided does not have permission to connect from the host you are using right now?

Comment: The user doesn't have any connection level restrictions.